# replace textlist with asterisk to ul li [php]

Tags: php

i got input from textarea like below

```
 * text1
n/ * text2
n/ * text3
n/text nolist
n/ * text1
n/ * text2
n/ * text3
```

so, i want to replace to be

```
<ul>
<li>text1<li>
<li>text2<li>
<li>text3<li>
</ul>
text nolist
<ul>
<li>text1<li>
<li>text2<li>
<li>text3<li>
</ul>
```

so what i want is someone input from textarea i got by $_post['textarea'] and then replace text i got from $_post['textarea'] to be html list

**i got it**

```
$text = preg_replace("/\-+(.*)?/i","<ul><li>$1</li></ul>",$_POST['text']);
echo $text = preg_replace("/(\<\/ul\>\n(.*)\<ul\>*)+/","",$text);
```

Answer (score 1):

list style with css will give you that solution
css:

```
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

html :

```
<ul>
  <li>your value</li>
  <li>your value</li>
</ul>
```

php str_replace :

```
$word = 'blablabla';
$str = str_replace("test", "good golly miss molly!", $word);
echo $str;

OR :
$arr = 'blablabla';
$bla = implode("<li>NEW BLABLABLA</li>",$arr);

echo $bla;
```

Comment: I mean from blablabla /n - text1/n - text2/n - text3/n  become p blablabla /p ol li text1 /li li text2/li li text3 /li /ol

Answer (score 0):

this is my code

```
$text = preg_replace("/\-+(.*)?/i","<ul><li>$1</li></ul>",$_POST['text']);
echo $text = preg_replace("/(\<\/ul\>\n(.*)\<ul\>*)+/","",$text);
```